# Which determiner in French means “any”

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot, déterminants

In English, the determiner *any* can mean each of four other determiners such as *all*, *some*, *every*, *none* (depending on the sentence it is in). So *any* is sometimes equivalent to a universal determiner, and sometimes not.

I'd like to know whether there is a determiner in French that has the same range of meanings as *any*. I know that  *tout* means *all*, *quelque* means for *some*, *chaque* means *every*, *aucun* means *none* in French.

BTW, in German *irgendein* is a determiner  like *any*.  In Chinese, it is "任何" like *any*.

Comment: "Any" is not a universal determiner in English: [Universal determiners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_determiners#Universal_determiners). To my knowledge the concept on "universal determiner" does not exist in French grammar.  Your using "universal determiner" for *irgendein* (ein unbestimmter  Bestimmungswort/Determiner) makes me wonder if you are not using "universal" wrongly. Would you by any chance mean "undefined" and no "universal"?  Again you need to be more specific, include more details.

Comment: As it is maybe your question would be better on [linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: *Quelque* can mean "some" but it can also mean "any", "about", "a few"... *Chaque* can mean "each" or "every".

Comment: The google translate gives *quelconque* for *any*. But translation only has any and some, not all and none.

Comment: Yes, this question could be better suited for the linguistic site. But the site is almost exclusively in English.

Comment: "Any" would translate as *quelconque* in very few cases, it can translate as "some" or "even "ordinary". Linguistics is not exclusively about English, even if they might clarify for you the concept of "universal determiner", which to my knowledge, "any" isn't. French grammar doesn't have the concept.  Again, you should check the various meanings of "any" before anything else. It has so many meanings your question is not suited for FL.

Comment: Perhaps he's thinking of the logical term "universal", and misapplying it to "any", which is the existential determiner?

Comment: @LukeSawczak Then they should clarify what they mean by "universal" and FL is not the site to do it. Asking the same question over and over again won't solve their (mis)understanding of "any" and the concept of "universal determiner". And FL is not the place to give the different meanings of "any".

Comment: Thanks. I made a mistake. *Any* is not a universal determiner in general but sometimes is equivalent to a universal determiner, and sometimes not. I have modified it and is appreciated if the downvote can be removed.

Answer (score 1):

"None" is not a determiner but a pronoun. No, there is no unique word that could be used to translate "any" in French. There is quite a number of possibilities, and some of them, among which important ones, are given below. At times "any" is not translated as a single word but instead  in combination with other words.

- **1/** [all] **Any** loose knot must be done over again. → **Tout** nœud mal serré doit être refait. *or* **Tous les** nœuds mal serrés doivent être refaits.
- **2/** [every] This has to be done **any** time you notice a leak. → Il faut faire cela **toutes** les fois que vous remarquez une fuite. *or* Il faut faire cela **chaque** fois que vous remarquez une fuite.
- **3/** [some] I don't want **any** soup. → Je ne veux pas **de** soupe.
- **4/** They didn't see **any** books on the shelves. → Ils n'ont pas vu **de** livres sur les étagères.
- **5/** She doesn't want **any** soup, she wants turtle soup! ("any" is stressed) → Elle ne veut pas **d**'une soupe **quelconque**, elle veut de la soupe à la tortue. *or* Elle ne veux pas **n'importe quelle** soupe, Elle veut de la soupe à la tortue !
- **6/** Ask **any** doctor — They'll tell you that alcohol is a poison. (*Practical English Usage*) ("any" is stressed) → Demandez à **n'importe** quel docteur, il vous dira que l'alcool est un poison.
- **7/** He knows French **if any man does**. (Harrap's) → Il sait le français **comme pas un**. (Harrap's)
- **8/** He hasn't **any more** money. (Harrap's) → Il n'a **plus** d'argent.
- **9/** **If it is in any way inconvenient**, don't do it. (Harrap's) → **Pour peu que cela vous dérange**, ne le faites pas. (Harrap's)
- **10/** If it is in **any** way inconvenient, don't do it. (Harrap's) → Si en **quelque** façon cela vous dérange, ne le faites pas. (user LPH)

Comment: I upvote this, but are you sure that *none* is not a determiner and why do you think it is not?

Comment: @hermes Yes, I am sure; first I have the certitude to have never seen it used before a noun and then this is confirmed by [OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/none_1?q=none) that defines it as a pronoun (comparatively rarely, it is an adverb, as in "_none the wiser_").

Comment: But see [here](https://wordtype.org/of/none) where it is defined as a determiner. That is probably why you get downvotes.

Comment: @hermes I believe that source is wrong; it provides no instance of use as a determiner. Take a look at these other dictionaries: [Merriam](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/none?src=search-dict-hed), [lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/none), [MacMillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/none), [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/none), [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/none), [Free](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/none), [Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/none). Collins: "quantifier", no POS.

Comment: I think it is not well defined and that is why there exist some differences. It is sure that *none of* is a determiner.  Your post is fine except this problem and that is why you get downvotes.

Comment: @hermes This is not the reason of the downvotes, I can assure you that there would be comments showing some reference proving that "none" is a determiner. When there is no comment, the reason is clear.  // Your  theory does not hold: for instance in  "none of you will succeed", if "none" were a determiner, then it would determine "you", but a personal pronoun never has a determiner. By the way, do you know the reason for the downvote _you_ get?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez L'expression « présenter un inconvénient » est courante ([ngram](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22pr%C3%A9sente%20un%20inconv%C3%A9nient%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)); Pourquoi l'avoir changée ?

Comment: Parce qu'en anglais « inconvenient » ne veut pas dire ça. Un inconvénient ce serait « drawback ».

Comment: @LPH, the reason for the downvote of my post is that I made a mistake in assuming *any* is a universal determiner, and I modified that.

Comment: @hermes That is not sufficient for a downvote; plenty of questions are accepted that have worse errors than that one; such errors are corrected though comments or as in the case of the present question directly in an answer, as it is sometimes preferable to preserve an error in the text. // Are you still convinced that "none" is a determiner (might not be an error from your point of view? haha!)

Comment: @LPH, I am not sure if *none* is a determiner or not. There are sources as I showed you saying that it is. But this is not the most important because I only ask which determiner in French is like *any*.  It seems that there is no such determiner in French.

Comment: Usually “none” is a pronoun. As previously noticed it can also be an adverb. In “none of” it can be argued that it is part of a determiner. Notice that the related word “no” is also a determiner. E.g. *No words can explain this.*

Comment: Je n'ai pas d'avis et c'est vraiment une coïncidence, mais c'est facile de manquer des trucs dans Wiktionnaire et j'ai remarqué qu'ils ont un emploi [régional](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/none#Determiner), sinon ils disent _archaïque_ pour cette classe-là.

Comment: @escarlateadamantine Intéressant, un véritable contexte syntaxique de détermination…mais un usage de portée régionale plutôt limitée.